# I am having trouble printing a list of my created objects in F#. This is what i have so far.?

Tags: list, object, f#

```
module Classes =

    type Student(name : string, age : int) =
        member this.Name = name
        member this.Age = age

    /// An instances of the students class
    let student1 = Student("bob", 20)
    let student2 = Student("sally",18)
    let student3 = Student("frank",22)
    let student4 = Student("lisa",19)
    let student5 = Student("john",17)


    printfn "student 1: %s, age: %d" student1.Name student1.Age
    printfn "student 2: %s, age: %d" student2.Name student2.Age
    printfn "student 3: %s, age: %d" student3.Name student3.Age
    printfn "student 4: %s, age: %d" student4.Name student4.Age
    printfn "student 5: %s, age: %d" student5.Name student5.Age



    let studentList =  [student1; student2; student3; student4; student5]  

  //  studentList |> List.iter (printf "%s , %d")
    printfn "%O" studentList
    printfn "%A" studentList
    studentList |> List.iter (printf "%s" Student)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the correct code:

```
studentList |> List.iter (fun s -> printf "Name: %s, Age: %s" s.Name s.Age)
```

Or this:

```
studentList |> List.iter (printf "%A")
```

I really can't think of where to start explaining what is wrong with your original version... For starters, why are you passing `Student` as second argument to `printf` on the last line? You don't even have that defined anywhere, so it's a bit puzzling. Secondly, I wouldn't use class for this kind of model, a record would be much better suited.

I would really, really encourage you to gain some theoretical knowledge about F# before embarking on a project. One resource I can wholeheartedly recommend is [fsharpforfunandprofit.com](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/learning-fsharp/).

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am  a really new to F# and was just trying to make sense of it using some of my knowledge in things like java. I will definitely into the article.

Comment: If your prior experience is limited to Java, then you most certainly need a crash course in order to make sense of things. F# is very different from Java in some very fundamental respects. In the mean time, if my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it?